# React component is triggering unwanted navigation/uri query

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been working with React for YEARS and have yet to encounter this phenomenon. If you can crack it, you'll be my hero forever

### The Setup

I have a shared component. It is a wrapper for some buttons that appear at the bottom of several different pages (most use cases are steps in a form. The last of those buttons ALWAYS throws a modal to cancel setup.

I am using the shared component in ALL the following use cases:

1. ✔ The first page of a multi-step form. Works fine, throws modal.
2. ✔ The second page of a multi-step form. Works fine, throws modal.
3. ❌ The third page of a multi-step form. **Fails**. See description below
4. ❌ The fourth page of a multi-step form. **Fails**
5. ✔ The review page after the form is completed. Works fine again.

The component itself contains just a button that triggers a `useState()` setter locally, which toggles the modal open/closed.

### The Problem

On the pages where it doesn't work, the component throws all the form values on the page up into the URL as a query string.
[see image - green underlined portion is added on modal trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkEcp.png)

This triggers a page reload and of course things break.

### Expected Result

I should be able to click "cancel" button and the modal pops. Nothing more, nothing less.

### The (relevant) code

```js
const IntakeLossButtons = ({
    // PRIMARY BUTTON PROPS
    buttonText,
    onButtonClick,
    buttonDisabled,
    buttonSpinning,
    buttonAriaLabel,
    // CANCEL LINK AT BOTTOM
    idToCancel,
    saveAction,
    onCancel
}) => {
    const [showCancelModal, setShowCancelModal] = useState(false)

    return (
        <div className={styles.buttonsWrapper}>
            <SpinnerButton
                type="primary"
                text={buttonText}
                disabled={buttonDisabled}
                spinning={buttonSpinning}
                onClick={onButtonClick}
                ariaLabel={buttonAriaLabel}
            />

            <button 
                className="btnLink"
                id="cancel-id" 
                tabIndex="0" 
                aria-label={translations.cancelBtnAria ||"Opens a modal to cancel your claim"} 
                color="secondary" 
                onClick={()=>setShowCancelModal(true)}
            >
                Cancel Setup
            </button>
            
            <CancelModal
                isOpen={showCancelModal}
                idToCancel={idToCancel}
                onCancel={onCancel}
                onSaveForLaterAction={saveAction} 
                onCloseModal={()=>setShowCancelModal(false)}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default IntakeLossButtons;
```

### WTF?

What would cause this type of behavior? I have tried googling and reading what might cause this. I have logged everything I can log and I still don't know what is causing such a weird behavior.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe you forgot to do:

```
 e.preventDefault();
```

inside the `onSubmit` handler of your form.  In fact, it looks like you don't even have a `<form>` at all, just a `<button>` (one with no `type` attribute, which means it will default to being a *submit* button).

You need to wrap the button in a `<form>` with such a submit handler.   If you don't do that, when you "submit the form" (ie. click the button) it will use all the form's inputs to generate a new URL, and then it will send you to do that URL.

This is the "default" behavior for forms in browsers.  If you go to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), for instance, and search for "cute puppies", you'll see the URL changes to have `?q=cute+puppies`, because Google relies on *not* preventing this default behavior.